# Joomla JAuthentication: :authenticate error

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla1.7

i had to upgrade our joomla website.So i upgraded  from verion 1.7.5 to 2.5.16 with no errors. and everything is ok.i can login logout etc..

then i tried to upgrade to 3.2 .when done i had  "500 JHtml icon not supported. File not found" error.When i couldnt fix the problem.i decided to upload my backup which is joomla 1.7.5.

when i get to the main page i see this long error..

"Unknown column 'a.title_alias' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.title_alias, a.introtext, a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by, a.created_by_alias, CASE WHEN a.modified = 0 THEN a.created ELSE a.modified END as modified, etc etc etc."

and when i tried to login. it gives me the long error

"JAuthentication: :authenticate: Uyumlu ek yükleme başarısız: plgauthenticationcookie
Kullanıcı adı ve parola eşleşmiyor ya da henüz bir hesabınız yok.
Unknown column 'a.title_alias' in 'field list' SQL=SELECT a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.title_alias, a.introtext, a.checked_out, a.checked_out
.... etc etc etc"

and now i can not login to administrator page.tried some solutions ,but i can not even find the jos_plugins. it does not exist anymore.

i would be glad if someone helps me.

and by the way ,i didnt not backup my database

Comment: It sees as though you did not update the database schema. If you go to administrator/components/com_admin/sql you will get a list of all of the sql changes you need to run. Do that and you'll have the right columns and tables.

Comment: thanks but , can you be more specific. i can not login to the administrator area of joomla.

Comment: do you mean the "list of the changes" in my 1.7.5 backup ? and run them ? in which order? and i dont want to lose my data on stuod_users etc..

Comment: ? there are a bunch of sql files, you need to run them.  Obviously make a back up first.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't back up your database, you may check with your host if they have a backup.

If not, your database schema was updated to 3.2 which is not backwards compatible, so just reapply the 3.2 update package from ftp / ssh.

The login issue is due to the new double factor authentication plugin not having saved its parameters; in a normal installation, you would just open the plugin's options and save.

Since you don't have access, now you are best off disabling the two factor authentication plugin from the database, simply disable it from the db:

```
UPDATE `#__extensions` SET `enabled`=0 WHERE name like 'plg_twofactorauth_totp'
```

(replace `#_` with your database prefix, you can find that out reading the configuration.php)

Then you should be back to your first error, `500 JHtml icon not supported. File not found`.

First, upgrade all your extensions (components, modules, plugins) with the latest version, ensuring it's compatible with J 3+ and possibly J 3.2.

If after this you still get the error, you'll need to find the source, most likely in the template, but it could be anywhere. If it's only on the frontend, try different pages; if it only shows on one page, it's in a component; if it's everywhere, it could be either the template or a plugin; try disabling all non-core plugins selectively to spot the offending one, then disable it to confirm.